# scala timing problems with add stuff to a seq

Tags: scala, playframework

I've got a question that concerns scoping in scala. I have a function like this:

```
def getElements(id: Int): Seq[Element] = {
    var test = ""
    dto.getElementIds(id).map {
      elementIds => {
        test += " hello "
        elementIds.foreach(elementId => dto.getElement(elementId).map {
          case Some(element) => test += " hi "
                println("ThirdPrint: " + test)
        })
        println("SecondPrint: " + test)
      }
    }
    println("FirstPrint: " + test)
}
```

Lets say "elementsIds" has a lenght of 2.
The console says:
FirstPrint:
SecondPrint: hello
ThirdPrint: hello hi
ThirdPrint: hello hi hi
Why is scala doing that? I would assume that third print is executed first. By the time I get to the "FirstPrint" the "hi"'s are gone. Why is the last line of code executed first?
I'm working with slick and Futures, does this have something to do with it? Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Thanks, works fine.
Is it possible to return a seq instead? Like this:

```
 def getElements(id: Int): Future[Seq[Element]] = {
    var mySequence: Seq[Element] = Seq()
    val elementsIds: Future[Seq[Int]] = dto.getElementIds(id)
    var test = ""
    val elementsF = elementsIds.flatMap {
      elementIds => {
        test += " hello "
        val idsAsElements: Seq[Future[Element]] = elementIds.map(elementId => dto.getElement(elementId).collect {
          case Some(element) => mySequence = mySequence :+ element
        })
        val idsAsElementsF: Future[Seq[Element]] = Future.sequence(idsAsElements)
        idsAsElementsF.onComplete(_ => println("SecondPrint: " + test))
        idsAsElementsF
      }
    }
    elementsF.onComplete(_ => println("FirstPrint: " + test))
    elementsF
  }
```

Is it possible to return "mySequence" whenever idsAsElements is "onComplete"?

Comment: Is `dto.getElementIds(id)` returning a `Future`? Can you provide the types?

Comment: yes Future[Seq[Int]] (ids)

Comment: So, it's running in a parallel thread in the background. While your `FirstPrint` is executed in line, the other thread is still working on getting those ids from where it gets them, once that happens, the `.map` gets executed.

Comment: okay and how can I resolve this?

Comment: Solve what? That's the expected behaviour. What do you want to happen?

Comment: I've added `Await.result(` around now it works ... but I think thats not a good solution rightß

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 object X {
  import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
  case class Element()
  object dto{

    def getElementIds(i: Int):  Future[Seq[Int]] = Future(Seq(1,2,3))
    def getElement(i: Int):  Future[Option[Element]] = Future(Some(Element()))

  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    getElements(0)
    Thread.sleep(10000) // waiting logs
  }
  def getElements(id: Int): Future[Seq[Element]] = {
    val elementsIds: Future[Seq[Int]] = dto.getElementIds(id)
    var test = ""
    val elementsF = elementsIds.flatMap {
      elementIds => {
        test += " hello "
        val idsAsElements: Seq[Future[Element]] = elementIds.map(elementId => dto.getElement(elementId).collect {
          case Some(element) => test += " hi "
            println("ThirdPrint: " + test)
            element
        })
        val idsAsElementsF: Future[Seq[Element]] = Future.sequence(idsAsElements)
        idsAsElementsF.onComplete(_ => println("SecondPrint: " + test))
        idsAsElementsF
      }
    }
    elementsF.onComplete(_ => println("FirstPrint: " + test))
    elementsF
  }
}
```

output:

ThirdPrint:  hello  hi

ThirdPrint:  hello  hi  hi

ThirdPrint:  hello  hi  hi  hi

SecondPrint:  hello  hi  hi  hi

FirstPrint:  hello  hi  hi  hi

Comment: Do not forget if you use .map you have to cover all cases
 .map{ case Some(a) => ...} fails on none

Comment: Do you want to receive from the function the first completed idsAsElements and skip other?

Comment: I want to append the return value (Some(element)) like this: `mySequence = mySequence :+ element` from  `val idsAsElements: Seq[Future[Element]] = elementIds.map(elementId => dto.getElement(elementId).collect {...}`
and return that list I after its finished.

Comment: If you want  "list after it's finished" you can do Await.result(elementsF, duration) in the code above.
But it is a bad idea, this function have to return Future in other case you block the main thread.
There is only one reason to use var, if using val is a bottleneck and you need to improve performance. 
There are two reasons to use Await.result. The first is debugging code, the second is unit testing.

Comment: is there no other way instead of await?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148389/discussion-between-felix-and-ivan).

Comment: It's like you turn on a kettle and want a boiling water. There are two ways: 
1. Stay and wait == Await.result
2. Go to watch TV and go back on signal == return Future and do other work
So there are not other way to return Seq[Element]. only Await.result

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's not a good solution. You should avoid blocking in your code, except, maybe at the highest possible level (`main` method). Also, mutable state is bad, especially, when combined with concurrency (futures).

Your function should return a `Future`. Something like this will work (I am not sure if I guess the intent of your code correctly - your function was declared to return `Seq[Element]`, but written to return a `Unit` ... I assume, that what you really wanted to return was the result of `getElement` calls for every id):

```
def getElements(id: Int): Future[Seq[Element]] = dto
   .getElementIds(id)
   .map { ids => ids.map(dto.getElement) }
   .flatMap(Future.sequence)
   .map(_.flatten)
```

I removed your printouts, because wasn't sure what was the purpose they serve (since the calls to dto.getElement are also happening in parallel, it is not obvious where and in which order you want those strings printed).

You could simulate your "expected output", by adding another transformation at the end for example:

```
  .andThen { case Success(results) => 
     val str = results.foldLeft("hello") { case (a,b) => 
        println("ThirdPrint: " + a + " hi")
        a + " hi"
     }
     println("SecondPrint: " + str)
     println("FirstPrint: " + str
  }
```